"TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'"
Here's my code. Someone please explain this error code and how do I fix it?
humanYears = {float(input("Imput Human Years:")):.2}
dogYears = 1

if humanYears <= 0.0:
    print("Human years may not be zero or negative")
else:
    if humanYears <= 1:
        dogYears = 15*humanYears
    elif humanYears <= 2:
        dogYears = 15+9*humanYears-1
    else:
        dogYears = 15+9+5*humanYears-2
    print("Dog Years =",dogYears)

I don't know what's happening, and I don't know what to change.

Your code seems to bee assuming that humanYears is a number, but maybe it is not.  Where is the value being initialized ?  Show that code as part of your question.

The problem is exactly as the error message states: you are comparing a dict and a float. The solution is to change the variable so that it is not a dict. What is the actual purpose of the code {float(input("Imput Human Years:")):.2}?

@ScaryWombat actually the code was in the post but not visible due to formatting used.   I have made an edit to correct that show it will show the initialization of humanYears.

The purpose of {float(input("Imput Human Years:")):.2} was to allow an input function to set the value for humanYears, the float is there so it sets to a decimal value. Without the fancy brackets, it gives me another error code. This is for a college lab and I clearly don't fully understand how to use this.

{something: somethingelse} creates a dictionary. You seem to be confusing that with f-string syntax, e.g. f"{variable:.2}"

This seems like a near-duplicate of this post, though I'm hesitant.

@Maverick float(input(...)) is perfectly sensible. But why did you write {...:.2} around it? Were you trying to round the user input?

This line:
humanYears = {float(input("Imput Human Years:")):.2}

Actually defines a dict with single entry.   The input value (a string) converted to a float that is used as the key and .2 as the value associated with the key.
You confused the idea formatting in a string with affecting the float value brought in.
